# How to Change R factor value without changing levels?

Tags: r, factors, recode

Today I wanted to change values of my factor in R without changing the levels and order. I'm going crazy!

My variable looks like this:

```
str(df_2$sex)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "MALE", "FEMALE": 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1
```

I would like to change the value of "MALE" to = 0 and of "FEMALE" to 1.
It should look like this:

```
str(df_2$sex)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "MALE", "FEMALE": 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

Is there a way to do this without defining the variable as numeric?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't and keep it as a factor.  Factors are represented by integer codes from 1 to N levels.  Perhaps you could explain what your ultimate goal is here.  It shouldn't matter what the internal representation is unless perhaps when exporting the data to a different format.

Comment: The goal is to have a " classical " dummy Varialbe (as is common in the social sciences) as a factor.

Comment: if its a classical dummy variable, shouldnt it be df_2$sex_male with 2 level ("NO", "Yes") and 0, 0, 0, 1, 1... ?

Comment: you can always convert into a dummy by doing as.numeric(df_2$sex)-1.. sorry not quite sure what you need the 0,1 for. The reason it's 1,2 is because R is 1 based

Comment: R's base modelling functions will handle factor variables appropriately - you don't need to code them manually.

Comment: You need to change the order. It is not that hard to change it back. You could use `forcats::fct_rev()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. Sometimes, you want to implement things you don't need. 
What have I learned:

- R counts from 1.
- Factors are practical and hardly need any processing.
- I urgently need to look at the package forcats.

With kind regards
aeoneo